# How to specify the color of bars in a table plot in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, plot

Suppose I have data `D`. I `cut` this data into 3 pieces. How can I assign a different color to each piece of the data in an R plot?

***Note:*** I'm interested in a functional answer for data cut in any number of pieces.

Here is my data and R code (without success):

```
# DATA
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m/master/t.csv", h = TRUE)

# cut in 3 pieces
g <- table(cut(D$time, 
               breaks = c(-Inf, 4, 12, Inf), 
               include.lowest=TRUE))

# color DATA based on pieces: [0-4], [6-12], [24-40]
plot(table(D$time), col = (1:3)[g])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# DATA
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m/master/t.csv", h = TRUE)

# cut in 3 pieces    
g <- cut(as.numeric(names(table(D$time))), 
               breaks = c(-Inf, 4, 12, Inf), 
               include.lowest=TRUE)

# color DATA based on pieces: [0-4], [6-12], [24-40]
plot(table(D$time), col = g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The trick to coloring points in base R plotting is to specify a "short" vector of colors (e.g., `col_vec <- c("red", "blue")`) and then to specify the usually "long" vector of categories for your points/lines (e.g., `cat_vec <- c(2,2,1,2,2,1,1)`.  And then to use the argument `col = col_vec[cat_vec]` in the call to `plot()`.

This will do essentially the same thing for your desire to plot a table object:

```
# identify the categories of each row of data
D$cat <- cut(D$time, breaks = c(-Inf, 4, 12, Inf))

# get a vector of the colors -- one color per group
color_vec <- colorRampPalette(c(4,2))(length(unique(D$cat)))

# get a vector of the color per value of D$time
category_vec <- aggregate(cat ~ time, data=D, function(i) mean(as.integer(i)))[,2]

# plot it as described in paragraph above
plot(table(D$time), col=color_vec[category_vec])
```

[image]